# Anidar texto en C

Tags: python, c, condiciones

Buenos dias/tardes/noches.

Tengo un inconveniente.
Quiero anidar valores *numericos* entre valores tipo *string* en el printf de **C**.

Para que se entienda bien, en **Python** seria así:

```
num = int(input("Ingresa un numero: "))

if num > 0 :
    print(f"{num} es mayor que 0")
elif num<0:
    print(f"{num} es menor que 0")
else:
    print(f"{num} es igual que 0")
```

Quiero saber si es posible hacerlo en **C**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Ingresa un numero: %i\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    if (num>0){
        printf("Es mayor que 0. Tu numero es: %i\n",num);
    }
    else if (num<0){
        printf("Es menor que 0. Tu numero es: %i\n",num);
    }
    else{
        printf("Es igual que 0. Tu numero es: %i\n",num);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Si no existe una forma tambien diganme por favor.
Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿ Has intentado poner el `%i` en otro sitio del texto ?

Comment: @Trauma. Yo creo que busca poder poner una expresión dentro del string, tal como lo hace Python, de tal manera de pasar sólo un argumento a `printf`, no dos o más como ahora.

Comment: No entiendo... lo que preguntas ¿no es lo que hace el código que tú mismo has puesto en C? En ese código el valor de `%i` es sustituido por `num` por lo que equivale al `f"{num}"` de python.

Comment: @abulafia. El problema en C es que tiene que poner un %i donde quiere el valor. Mirando el string, no se ve de donde venga el valor; hay que mirar al siguiente argumento del printf.

Comment: Si existe una forma, es la segunda parte del codigo que tu tienes alli. Si lo que quieres es colocarlo en la string como lo haria un f string en python, tendrias que usar `sprintf`

Comment: No, no se puede. En C no existe **string interpolation**.

Answer (score 0):

ya pude solucionarlo el otro dia

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n1, n2;
    printf("Que numero es mayor?\n");

    printf("Ingresa el primer entero: ");
    scanf("%i", &n1);

    printf("Ingresa el segundo entero: ");
    scanf("%i", &n2);

    if (n1>n2){
        printf("%i es mayor que %i\n", n1, n2);
    }
    else if (n2>n1){
        printf("%i es mayor que %i\n", n2, n1);
    }
    else{
        printf("Ingresa dos numeros diferentes");
    }

return 0;
}
```

No es la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero era para una tarea. Uno habia dicho que pruebe cambiar de lugar los %i. Me sirvio, muchas gracias :D